# Range of $f(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{1+x^{2}+y^{2}}$ with a certain domain

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

> Let, $E=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^{2}:|x|\le 1, |y|\le 1\}.$ Define $f:E\to \mathbb R$ by $$f(x,y)=\dfrac{x+y}{1+x^{2}+y^{2}}.$$
>
> Then the range of $f$ is a
>
> (a) connected open set.
>
> (b) connected closed set.
>
> (c) bounded open set.
>
> (d) closed & unbounded set.

We find that $\bigl|f(x,y)\bigr|\le 1$. So $f$ is bounded. But how we find the range of $f$ or without finding the range of $f$ how we detect that connected or not & open or not & closed or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to consider: is $f$ continuous? what topological properties might $E$ have? Some basic theorems of topology may be applicable.

Comment: The function is continuous, $E$ is connected. So image of $f$ of also connected.OK. But what about closed & open?

Comment: $E$ has another topological property that is preserved under continuous maps.